# Переписать кусок кода на другой язык

Tags: php, python-3.x

Есть кусок кода,написанный в python, с помощью api йобита выводит цену по определенной паре.

```
def get_course():
    resBTC = requests.get('https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/1_2')    
    resBTC_obj = json.loads(resBTC.text)
    return resBTC_obj['1_2']['last']
```

Может кто-нибудь переписать этот кусок на пхп?
В итоге нужно, чтоб я переменной присваивалось значение return resBTC_obj['1_2']['last']

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так

```
function get_course() {
   $data = file_get_contents("https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/1_2");
   $data = json_decode($data, true);
   return $data['1_2']['last'];
}
```

Comment: Вроде работает, а можно как-то преобразовать число? сейчас оно выводится с экспонентой, как сделать округление до 6 знака после запятой?

Comment: @Midnight $rounded = round(get_cource(), 6);

Comment: <?php
function get_course() {
   $data = file_get_contents("https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/1_2");
   $data = json_decode($data, true);
   return $data['1_2']['last'];
}
$rounded = round(get_cource(), 6);
echo $rounded;
?> Выдает Call to undefined function get_cource()

Comment: $rounded = round(get_course(), 6);

Comment: извините, у вас есть телеграмм? хочется задать пару вопросов